# how to validate image dimension using laravel 4

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel. I am trying to validate dimensions of image using Laravel.
My controller.php code is here:

```
public function getgallery()
  {
    $validate=Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
      'galname' => 'required|max:20',
      'galimg'  => 'required|max:400kb|Mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png,pneg'
    ));

     $validate->sometimes('galimg', 'required', function($input)
     {
         //psudo code, here validate your image

         return imagesx($input) > 400 && imagesy($input) > 400;
     });

     if($validate->fails())
     {
         return Redirect::route('getgallery')->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
     }
```

But I get an error:

> ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given
>   http:// ErrorException
>   …\app\controllers\AddgalleryController.php19

I am not using custom validation rule.
 how to solve this error?

Comment: For the images in my laravel projects I use: [stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler).

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like is $input, is an object, probably you can use `$input['file']`

Comment: $validate->sometimes('galimg', 'required', function($input['file'])
       {
       
          return imagesx($input['file']) > 400 && imagesy($input['file']) > 400;
       });
i got another error 
http://Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_PARSE)

syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: We need unseated what object is $input. On method sometimes var_dump $input, here you can see the type of object.

Comment: Iam trying var_dump($input);   i got result is this object(Illuminate\Support\Fluent)#249 (1) { ["attributes":protected]=> array(4) { ["galname"]=> string(3) "ggh" ["_token"]=> string(40) "62gaN6ipoSQaOxZRXQMN6mgs4vE5dHfS8v9pKzp6" ["sub"]=> string(11) "Add Gallery" ["galimg"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>bool(false["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(11) "images5.jpg"

Comment: ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>string(10)"image/jpeg["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(5842) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php7090.tmp" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(11) "php7090.tmp" } } }